# React Components "flickers" on load, since state gets overriden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I work on a todo app with React and things become clearer, but I struggle to undersand the "lifecycle". In VueJS I know a `ComponentDidMount()` hook, which would help me to solve this issue if I guess, but in React I can´t find it out.

I have an array of todos like this: `const todos = [{description: "walk dog", done: false}]`

This is the initial state of my app:

```
const [alltodos, handleTodos] = useState([]);
```

On load I use this `useEffect` hook to get data from localStorage.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const items = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    const parsed = JSON.parse(items);
    handleTodos(parsed);
  }, []);
```

I count my todos with this function:

```
  const countTodos = () => {
    const donetodos = alltodos.filter((item) => {
      return !item.done;
    });

    countOpen(donetodos.length);
  };
```

I update the count if a dependency changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    countTodos();
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(alltodos));
  }, [alltodos]);
```

So what happens is that the counter starts with 0 and than "flickers" for a milisecond before it shows the number of todos which I get from localstorage.

Is there a way to prevent that behaviour? As far as I know the component gets rendered FIRST and then the useEffect hook gets triggered. How I render my component AFTER the data is pulled from localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be with a [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state). Also, cleaning up the variables and using a standardized [variable, setVariable] will save you headache debugging in the future.

```
const [alltodos, setAlltodos] = useState(() => {
    const items = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    const parsed = JSON.parse(items);
    return parsed || "";
});
```

Comment: thank you, while the other solutions also works, this is much easier and I guess the best way to handle it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `allTodos` state with `null`. As long as this state is `null`, render a notification or just return `null` to render nothing.

You can calculate the open todos count directly from the current `alltodos` state, without the need of `useEffect`.

```
const [alltodos, handleTodos] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const items = localStorage.getItem("todos");
  const parsed = items ? JSON.parse(items) : [];
  handleTodos(parsed);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(alltodos));
}, [alltodos]);

if(alltodos === null) return 'Loading todos list';

// this is derived from state, so you don't have to create a state for it
const openTodosCount = alltodos.reduce((acc, o) => acc + !o.done, 0);
```

Comment: thank you, very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to add new state that would be responsible for loading.
For example

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

set it initially on true and then after you do all your calculations change it to `false`.

Then you can depend on that state and show `div` with a text `"Loading"` or anything else but when `isLoading` would go to `false` it will show component elements.

Comment: I tried that and it did not really work. Where to put the useState function.

I tried to put it below `handleTodos(parsed)`  (`setIsLoading(false);`)and it still behaves the same way.